# Compatibility between the Microsoft Graph Toolkit and Fluent UI styling

Tags: reactjs, forms, fluent-ui, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am building Web forms that use a mix of [Microsoft Graph Toolkit components (React flavor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-react) and Fluent UI components.

What is the proper way to style those forms? Are the Fluent UI styles going to work seamlessly on mgt components as well, or are there limitations to be aware of?

Comment: The mgt components were built based on m365 styles, and are customizable through the custom css properties or associated themes. The integration of FluentUI would be up to the developer to implement (I believe there has been some [success](https://twitter.com/joaojmendes/status/1332459908869066752) ) , is there a specific instance or example you have?

Comment: @NicVogt One component I am interested in is PeoplePicker (React version of mgt-people-picker). Are you saying that the React mgt styling is the exact same as no-framework mgt styling?

Comment: Yup! mgt-react was built with the same intentions and styles as the regular web components components themselves. If you intend to use a features that specifically style components (theming) you might find collisions, but that's about it.

Comment: ok thx. Feel free to post this as answer so I can accept it. Would you have example of collisions? In particular with Fluent UI Northstar?